# Minecraft Server help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So im hosting a smp for minecraft and the server is running off of a pc somewhere else in my house all my friends can connect to and it says full green bars and everything when i try joining buit when i trying connecting all it says is connecting to server and nothing else it just fails to connect the server is there any way to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We'll need more information before we can figure out what the issue may be and then help you with it. How is your network set up? What are your firewall and port forwarding settings if any? What is your server version and is it a vanilla or modded server? How are you trying to connect to it and how are your friends trying to connect  to it?

Comment: @Alay Perez if an answer has answered you, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark that will be available under the vote button on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to connect to your public IP address, connecting to that will (in most cases) not work, you have to connect to the machines local ip if you're in the local network.

Next time try to better explain what you're doing when you're getting this error, so people can help you better.

Comment: how can i find the local ip because localhost doesny work

Comment: @AlayPerez if its on a Windows machine, open CMD and type `ipconfig` and look for the IPv4 address under ethernet/wireless adapter. If its on a Linux machine, type `ifconfig` or `ip address` and look for the 'inet' under ethX or wlanX.